# best practice to render html tags

Tags: html, api, frontend

The backend API returns the data as a list -

```
"textList": [
             "Item 1",
             "<span class=\"rr-bold\">Some data.</span> More data in item 2.",
             "Item 3"
]
```

I've not set HTML to render. We own the backend API as well.

Seeking for best practice here:

1. If I remove HTML tags from second list-item, should I send it separately from backend to indicate that this needs to follow different style?
2. Should I create the style in rendering app to make it bold? Sounds loosely coupled. Style name change in backend can break rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you want to achieve. To answer your questions:

1. Since you have no ID or any other way to distinguish between the elements the easiest way is to re-send the whole list - if I understand you correctly. HTML sent from backend is always in string format and if you remove the tags it's just another string. I don't understand what you mean by sending it separately.
2. Styling can only been done in CSS that runs on the client browser. Or what do you mean?